# Pretend to be a tty in bash for any command

Tags: bash, tty

Whenever I use `grep`, and I pipe it to an other program, the `--color` option is not respected. I know I could use `--color=always`, but It also comes up with some other commands that I would like to get the exact output of that command as the output I would get if I was in a tty.

So my question is, is it possible to trick a command into thinking that the command is run inside a tty ?

For example, running

```
grep --color word file # Outputs some colors
grep --color word file | cat # Doesn't output any colors
```

I'd like to be able to write something like :

```
IS_TTY=TRUE grep --color word file | cat  # Outputs some colors
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527207/how-to-pretend-to-be-a-tty-when-trying-to-freebsd-update-from-a-shell-script) seems to have a tool that might do what I want :[empty - run processes and applications under pseudo-terminal (PTY)](http://empty.sourceforge.net/), but from what I could read in the docs, I'm not sure it can help for my problem

Comment: you realize that `--color` changes the actual data stream that is sent to command further down the pipeline? The consequence would be breaking other-wise reasonable code because `searchTarget` is not `^[32;4gsearchTarget^[32;h` (or similar). Good luck.

Comment: Yes I realize that, I will in my scripts never use that technique to color greps, but some commands that I use seem to output something different when used outside a tty (for example `ag` , the silversearcher, but also mocha, ...) and I don't have time to learn all the options to print with the same format whenever I pipe those commands into others)

Comment: Hmmm.. I think this has come up before with some surprising answers (to me). Did you search much for `[linux] (or) [bash] --color`? Good luck.

Comment: I searched a bit, but haven't found anything that would solve my issue.

Comment: Have you tried any of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401002/trick-an-application-into-thinking-its-stdin-is-interactive-not-a-pipe

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233808/piping-data-to-linux-program-which-expects-a-tty-terminal

http://rachid.koucha.free.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There are a number of options, as outlined by several other Stack Overflow answers (see [Caarlos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3009514/caaarlos)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32910661/pretend-to-be-a-tty-in-bash-for-any-command?newsletter=1&nlcode=138806%7c1c8b#comment53672609_32910661)).  I'll summarize them here though:

1. **Use `script` + `printf`**, requires no extra dependencies:

   ```
    0<&- script -qefc "ls --color=auto" /dev/null | cat
   ```

   Or make a bash function `faketty` to encapsulate it:

   ```
    faketty () {
        script -qefc "$(printf "%q " "$@")" /dev/null
    }
    faketty ls --color=auto | cat
   ```

   Or in the fish shell:

   ```
    function faketty
        script -qefc "(printf "%q " "$argv")" /dev/null
    end
    faketty ls --color=auto | cat
   ```

   (credit goes to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401002/trick-an-application-into-thinking-its-stdin-is-interactive-not-a-pipe/20401674#20401674))

   http://linux.die.net/man/1/script
2. **Use the `unbuffer` command** (as part of the `expect` suite of commands), unfortunately this requires an extra package install, but it's the easiest solution:

   ```
    sudo apt-get install expect-dev   # or brew install expect
    unbuffer -p ls --color=auto | cat
   ```

   Or if you use the fish shell:

   ```
    function faketty
        unbuffer -p $argv
    end
    faketty ls --color=auto | cat
   ```

   http://linux.die.net/man/1/unbuffer

This is a great article on how TTYs work and what Pseudo-TTYs (PTYs) are, it's worth taking a look at if you want to understand how the linux shell works with file descriptors to pass around input, output, and signals. http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php

Comment: Add `-e` to `script` to return the return value of the command. Also, consider piping to `less -FXur` which will display colours and not do anything if the output fits on a single screen (and fix a \r issue if you have it).

Comment: `script: illegal option -- f`  on macosx

Comment: `script -t 0` is equivalent to `script -f`, you can use those options instead on Mac.

Comment: Swop the c and the e

`script -qfec "$(printf "%q " "$@")"`

Comment: I was getting error with the "e" option last as @ErikMartino pointed out. Swapping made it work.

Comment: @StevieD I just hit the same issue and edited to make this change.

Comment: How can I use emualte tty when I need to run the program with `exec`, i.e. to keep the original shell PID?

Comment: @Mvorisek If you mean you want the child process's PID to take over and not `unbuffer`/`script`'s PID, then I don't think that's possible because both `script` and `unbuffer` are wrapper commands around the actual command, so by necessity they need different PID as long as the child command is running.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60279429/1356047 for a version that works on both Linux & MacOs AND supports returning status code

Comment: It must have been a while since this answer was written, but I just checked the install size of `expect` on archlinux and it is less than half 1MB

Comment: This only works on GNU systems, not BSD, so the "no dependencies" bit is far from correct. You need to add a switch to run different commands depending on the os.

Comment: @oligofren <1% of public systems run BSD, while I personally love BSD and run FreeBSD myself on one of my machines, you cannot reasonably expect every SO answer to be tailored towards BSD audiences. One of the skills BSD users rapidly acquire is being able to translate Linux solutions to BSD equivalents. If you have a correction you'd like to share for BSD, post it in comments!

Comment: macOS is BSD. That's why it's an important user group 

Comment: The `unbuffer` solution should work on macOS and other BSDs as far as I can tell. `brew install expect` or `pkg install expect`.

Comment: Concerning option 1, I'd recommend keeping the `/dev/null` part of the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20401674/4070848) or else you end up generating a `typescript` file with some content you probably don't need or even want.

Comment: Added it back, thanks @drmrbrewer

Comment: I get `/bin/bash: script: command not found`

Comment: Most distros include `script` out-of-the-box, but if you're on a system that doesn't have it you'll have to install the `util-linux` package @minseong. e.g. `apt install util-linux` or `brew install util-linux`.