# linux "watch -c" (with color parameter), but commands display colorless output. Why?

Tags: linux, terminal, command-line-interface

When I do 'ls', or 'service some_service_name status', or any other command with colored output, it, "surprisingly" :), shows it's output in color, but when I run them with 'watch' and even with 'watch -c' command with a color enabling parameter, they still show without colors.

Why?, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls` and others see that they are run from a script so they go to the default mode (without colors):

> With --color=auto, ls emits color codes only when standard output  is  connected  to  a terminal.

try forcing the color output:

```
watch -c ls --color
```

Comment: OK, I see, It worked for ls, but is there a color option for 'service' command? 'man service' has nothing about it.

Comment: I've found that 'service' command is just a bash script executing systemctl, but 'man systemctl' doesn't show anything about color either.

Comment: those commands check if it is an interactive (a tty) or non-interactive and don't show colors in the other case, I'm not sure if there is a way to force them to show always

Comment: And here's how to pretend a tty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32910661/pretend-to-be-a-tty-in-bash-for-any-command

Comment: Thanx, this gives me the solution to the problem. The faketty, in the example, didn't work for me, but @ least, I know now which direction to look at and I will read some information about tty now.

Comment: some commands accept `--ansi` to force ANSI output (eg coloured text) `watch -cn1 "git ls-files -m | xargs phplint --ansi --no-progress -w src/"`