# stdout/stdin and Parameters

Tags: c, pipe, stdout, stdin, getopt

I'm having a little problem with my programs and I don't know how to solve it. My programs work fine as long as I don't include `getopt`(without arguments).

I wrote 2 simple programs Server&Client

The Server writes numbers in `stdout` and the Client should read them with `stdin`.

Furthermore the programs should be able to get called with arguments(parameters).

**For example a call of the program looks like that:**

```
Terminal: ./Server -f72 | ./Client -r22
```

If I run the program then it just prints the "Her is r" with the argument "22" and "Waiting for Server", but it should print the numbers from the server

I am not able to find the mistake. I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance to all who read that.

**Server:**

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    FILE *ziel;
    ziel=stdout;

    int option;
    char buf[50];

    while ((option = getopt(argc, argv,"f:tr:d:j")) != -1)
    {
        switch (option)
        {
            case 'f' :
                strcpy(buf,optarg);
                break;
            case 't' :              
                break;
            case 'r' :
                strcpy(buf,optarg);
                break;
            default:
                //printf("1ERROR");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for(i=1;i>0;i++)
    {
        fprintf(ziel,"%d\n",i);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Client:**

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    FILE* cl;
    cl=stdin;
    int i;
    int zahl[10];
    int option;
    char buf[50];

    while ((option = getopt(argc, argv,"f:tr:")) != -1)
    {
        switch (option)
        {
            case 'f' :
                puts("Here is f");
                strcpy(buf,optarg);
                puts(buf);
                break;
            case 't' :
                puts("Here is t");
                break;
            case 'r' :
                puts("Here is r");
                strcpy(buf,optarg);
                puts(buf);
                break;
            default:
                printf("ERROR");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    puts("Waiting for Server");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        fscanf(cl,"%d",&zahl[i]);
        printf("Received %d\n ",zahl[i]);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: and running `./Server -f72` issues the numbers right?

Comment: Yes. I am using it in another programm too, where the parameters are important and the programm, at which  pipe it, just prints the argument string.

Comment: so this example above works? in that case it's not a [mcve]. Are you sure your other program does not use `stderr` and not `stdout`? You have to post the real case and console output. Are you _really_ sure that `getopt` is the culprit? because I seriously doubt it.

Comment: well i did it already yesterday. The example isnt working. I am sure that I use stdout i defined a pointer to it. I can post some terminal screenshots if you dont believe me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40874117/stdout-gets-overwritten-by-parameters?noredirect=1#comment68964570_40874117

Comment: I believe you have a problem, you wouldn't post a question just to annoy us :) I have doubts on the reproducer and on the cause, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your example has nothing to do with `getopt`. It's about *output buffering*.

If you wait long enough, a burst of numbers should appear in one go.

I made it work by modifying the server program

- removing the `sleep(1)`
- or using `fflush(stdout);` after the `fprintf`
- When printing in the terminal, the output is flushed when a linefeed is encountered, which explains why it works.
- When printing in a redirected output, buffering takes place. You have to explicitly flush the buffer (the C library could decide to flush anyway, but that's not what's happening here)

You cannot control that from your client. Even piping the server to `more` doesn't work in your case.

Read also here: [Does reading from stdin flush stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123528/does-reading-from-stdin-flush-stdout)

Note: you could fool your server program into believing it's writing in a `tty`, it's a bit hacky but could work:

[Pretend to be a tty in bash for any command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32910661/pretend-to-be-a-tty-in-bash-for-any-command)

(I currently don't have a Windows solution)

Comment: thanks a lot!!! I didn't thought on that. The sleep just simulated the time that I need to calculate the value i want to send,but it works now